# How do I find out which packages of qiskit are compatible with eachother?

Tags: qiskit, programming, qiskit-runtime

In particular I try to find out which version of `qiskit` is compatible with which version of `qiskit-ibm-runtime`. In my setup right now, both need different versions of `qiskit-aer` and `qiskit-ibmq-provider` or `qiskit-ibm-provider`. For `qiskit` there is [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html) documentation. Is there something similar for `qiskit-ibm-runtime`? Or ideally a list of compatibilities among the qiskit packages? Or can I retrieve the info using pip without installing the packages?

Edit: To make it more clear, I am looking for the information " `qiskit-ibm-runtime` version x will have no conflicting dependencies with `qiskit` version y."

Answer (score 1):

If you know where to find the repositories in GitHub you can look at the associated requirement files. So for qiskit-ibm-runtime you can look at https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/blob/main/requirements.txt and see that the current version has the following qiskit version requirements

- qiskit-terra>=0.25.0
- qiskit-ibm-provider>=0.6.3

You will need to pay attention to what version of the repo matches the release you are using if you did a "pip install" instead of cloning the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the problem you are having. Here some random ideas:

- You can find the release notes for `qiskit-ibm-runtime` [here](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-runtime/release_notes.html) and for `qiskit-ibm-provider` [here](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-provider/release_notes.html).
- The package [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) can help you to solve package conflicts.
- Check out requirements with `pip check`. For example, `pip check qiskit-ibm-runtime`
- For finding the dependencies with version number, check out https://www.wheelodex.org/ . For example, https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/qiskit-ibm-runtime/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  pipdeptree and pip check help to find conflicting dependencies more easily. But I am looking for a list of dependencies for each version of the two packages to find a combination that has no conflicts. Like wheelodox but for all versions, not only the latest.